# How to summon lightning bolt at normal (and not charged) creepers only?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I currently have this command: `execute at @e[type=minecraft:creeper] run summon minecraft:lightning_bolt`; but I have no idea where I should put the "{}" to check for the NBTs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nbt={}` as a target selector arguments.

As you know, not charged creepers have `{powered:0b}` in their nbt tags.

So `@e[type-creeper,nbt={powered:0b}]` is a command that detects not charged creeper.

Anyways, you would want to edit your command to
`execute at @e[type=minecraft:creeper,nbt={powered:0b}] run summon minecraft:lightning_bolt`